# Find duplicates in List<T>

Tags: c#, list

Let's say that I have 4 elements in my class: A,B,C and D, which I'm adding to list in my loop. I want to find these elements in my list, which have the same A,B & C values. Now I'm doing sth like this:

```
List<MyClass> ListMC = new List<MyClass>();

//do something
//read values from file and write them to a,b,c,d

if (ListMC.Any(k => k.A.Equals(a) && k.B.Equals(b) && k.C.Equals(c)))
{
    //write error to another list
    //it won't be add to ListMC
}
```

Is there any faster way to do this? Because when I'm adding really a lots of elements to ListMC and then it takes a lot of time to check it.

Any ideas? :)

====
Or I can add every time to list this elements (a,b,c,d) and then just remove these duplicates. But I still don't know fast way to do this.

Comment: How much faster are you hoping to get? This seems like a micro-optimization that you shouldn't be worried about. Also, I don't think you will find a faster way

Comment: You can't do it faster than linear time. The only wait is keep sort while adding elements into `ListMC` and use `BinarySearch`. Sorting after adding is in this case useless due to `n*log(n)` time. To find single elements is it not worth.

Comment: _"Or I can add every time to list this elements (a,b,c) and then just remove these duplicates."_ So what is the real requirement, what are you trying to achieve? Do you want to update the list with the new values if there is already one with the same a,b and c values?

Comment: @Sayse It just seems like a micro-optimization, but in my case I have to check tables in files, which have 2000 rows * 10 columns =20k elements in one file and there is 60 such files. And when I checked this operation takes the most time.
TimSchmelter: No, I don't want update, so I thought that the second option could delete these new duplicates if they were.

Comment: I don't doubt that it takes the most time but at the core you are just performing 3 required equality checks.

Comment: You are scanning 20k elements * 60 and applying a predicate to all of them, it's always going to be O(n) speed - you won't get any faster than that.

Comment: FYI: To remove duplicates after-the-fact, you can just use [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx). To detect them, you can [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the order, use a HashSet instead. It's a lot faster.

So instead use:

```
HashSet<MyClass> ListMC = new HashSet<MyClass>();

//do something
//read values from file and write them to a,b,c,d

if (ListMC.Any(k => k.A.Equals(a) && k.B.Equals(b) && k.C.Equals(c)))
{
    //write error to another list
    //it won't be add to ListMC
}
```

If ever you need order, you can convert using ToList(). For example:

```
List<MyClass> ConvertedToList = ListMC.OrderByDescending(x => x.C).ToList();
```

Comment: and then automatically `A`,`B`,`C` are compared?

Comment: I thought that HashSet remove only unique values in list, it's mean A,B,C & D, not only A,B,C. Can you explain this for me?

Comment: @TimSchmelter what do you mean? It's not automatically compared in the OP's question either.

Comment: @Tyress: but OP compares it manually. Using  `HashSet.Contains` does compare by reference by default.

Comment: @Monic I am not completely sure I understand, but don't worry about unique values as you're using a class, and classes with the same values are not equal (i.e. a MyClass myclass1 with values A = "Hello", B="World", C="To", D="You" won't be equal with a MyClass myclass2 with the same values so a HashSet will still allow both objects). My point was that you use your code and replace List<MyClass> with HashSet<MyClass>

Comment: @Tyress: so you're talking about this, that just change List<> to HashSet<> will speed up my operations? Ok, so then I'll check.

Comment: Yes. I had the same issue before. I always use HashSet by default ever since.

Comment: Now I can feel that it's faster. :) But if I want to have the order, what then I should do? Can I simply convert HashSet<> to List<>?

Comment: Yeah, just .ToList() it (assuming you're going to put ordering rules **after** it's a List)

Comment: Ok, so can you add this explanation to your main answer too? Then I accepted your answer.

Comment: @Tyress HashSet is based off of GetHashCode(), so it's not necessarily based on object equality. It's also important for OP to implement GetHashCode() correctly in this case.

Comment: @Monic To preserve the order, you have couple of options: (1) use _both_ HashSet and List. (2) use something like Dictionary<MyClass, int>, where int is the index, and [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) it after-the-fact. (3) store index in the MyClass itself, and also OrderBy.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic using a Dictionary or having the index in MyClass itself does seem like a great idea if Monic definitely wants to have order at some point. However I have a good feeling MyClass should be the value, and int the key in your example (therefore Dictionary<int, MyClass>)

Comment: @DanPantry yes Dan that's right...not sure why OP has to implement GetHashCode() though, or why it will ever become an issue.

Comment: @Tyress MyClass has to be the dictionary key to prevent duplicates.